# Server cannot read HTTPS POST request parameters using Retrofit2

Tags: android, aws-lambda, retrofit2

I'm trying to POST request to our AWS lambda server (`https://`) using Retrofit2 but the server cannot read the parameters I passed. But when I tried to use the same code pointing to our local network (`http://`) it works. Below is my code, please help.

Gradle Dependencies:

```
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
```

Request Class:

```
public class LoginRequest {

  @SerializedName("login_credential")
  private String credential;
  @SerializedName("password")
  private String password;

  public LoginRequest(String credential, String password) {
    this.credential = credential;
    this.password = password;
  }
}
```

Retrofit initialization:

```
public class ServerClient {

    public static Login getClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logger = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logger.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logger)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://my.server.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(Login.class);
    }

    public interface Login {
        @Headers("Accept: application/json")
        @POST("login")
        Call<LoginResponse> login(@Body LoginRequest request);
    }

}
```

The way I trigger the request:

```
Call<LoginResponse> call = ServerClient.getClient().login(new LoginRequest(email, password));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<LoginResponse> call, @NonNull Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                Log.e("response", "success");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<LoginResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Log.e("response", "failed");
        }
    });
```

Here's the log:

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://my.server.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/login
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 69
D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json
D/OkHttp: {"login_credential":"valid@email.com","password":"password"}
D/OkHttp: --> END POST (69-byte body)

D/OkHttp: <-- 400 https://my.server.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/login (966ms)
D/OkHttp: content-type: application/json
D/OkHttp: content-length: 138
D/OkHttp: date: Wed, 07 Mar 2018 05:16:54 GMT
D/OkHttp: x-amzn-requestid: c05224a1-21c6-11e8-b75f-3bdafa88fe40
D/OkHttp: access-control-allow-origin: *
D/OkHttp: x-amzn-remapped-content-length: 138
D/OkHttp: x-amzn-trace-id: sampled=0;root=1-5a9f75c6-a3b5a7897c5b8f9b73dbb419
D/OkHttp: x-cache: Error from cloudfront
D/OkHttp: via: 1.1 0932afdebb722b4465fd681f0h67865a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
D/OkHttp: {
D/OkHttp:     "message": {
D/OkHttp:         "login_credential": "Missing required parameter in the JSON body or the post body or the query string"
D/OkHttp:     }
D/OkHttp: }
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (138-byte body)
```

Comment: can you ask same thing with backend guy who sending this msg to you..

Comment: is the response ok in postman ??

Comment: yup. it also works on postman

Comment: In Backend which language you are using?

Comment: they're using python in the backend

Comment: I don't know this will help or not but in header delete the "Accept: " and write only application/json

Comment: And where's the LoginResponse? I see only LoginRequest. Maybe you need to change the Call<LoginResponse> login to Call<LoginRequest> login

Comment: LoginResponse is just a POJO for catching server response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue by adding some headers on our POST requests:

```
public interface Login {
    @Headers({"token: ",
        "accept-language: en-US",
        "accept: application/json",
        "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br"})
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    Call<LoginResponse> login(@Field("login_credential") String email,
                              @Field("password") String password);
}

Call<LoginResponse> call = SwapooClient.getClient().login(email, password);
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<LoginResponse> call, @NonNull Response<LoginResponse> response) {
        if (response.body() != null) {
            Log.e("response", "success");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<LoginResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
        Log.e("response", "failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is @Expose parameter also added also like:

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("error")
private ApiErrorNew error;

@Expose
@SerializedName("Status")
private String status;
```

Add the same and try.

Comment: Are you getting the same response, any change?

Comment: Also the text within the " " quotes in @SerializedName(" ") should match the the key parameter defined. Are they same?

Comment: yup it's the same but got the same response.